# How to send HTTP Error response in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

How to send error response in ruby if any invalid host requests web server.

As we do in java like below,

response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "InValid Host");

Can any one help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged it with Ruby on Rails I'm going to pass you the Rails method.

```
# in controller
render plain: 'InValid Host', status: :bad_request

# if you prefer a json response you might want to do
render json: {error: 'InValid Host'}, status: :bad_request
```

Check out the Rails Guide about this subject: [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)